# Concerns using a sound card as an oscilloscope using xosope

Tags: oscilloscope, signal-processing

Stated quite appropriately, I am in the "tinker with it and learn about it" stage of electronics.  Have assembled and played with some audio circuits, Arduino bare bones kits, some automotive add-ons, etc.

I have installed xoscope and interested in using it for the learning experience.  I've looked at a buffer / opamp circuit for the probes going into the sound card:
[image: schematic]

I have also just ordered in [these](https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10001&langId=-1&catalogId=10001&productId=2189880) probes to use.  According to the data sheet for the probes, they are designed and calibrated for use on any oscilloscope that has an input impedance of 1MΩ and whose input capacity is within the compensation range.

Now, again, I'm just a tinkerer, but don't want to damage the sound card.

Is such a buffer circuit really required for sound card input ?  I can also see the opamps in the schematic for x10?  amplification, but the probes I've ordered have that built-in.

I cannot foresee ever using the probes on mains, etc...  Just small-scale "peeking at what the signals are doing" kind of things.  Would just a 1M resistor between the probes and sound card suffice ?

Any knowledgeable advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The probes DO NOT contain any amplification.  If they are marked x10 then they divide the input by10, and you must multiply the voltage displayed on the scope by 10 to getthe correct voltage.

Comment: This buffer is a must if you are going to use your probes in X10 position. Soundcard input draws too much current. The probe in X10 position do not stand it and the signals under observation (very probably) either, if X1 is used. In X10 position there is extra 10MOhm between to protect your signals.

Comment: Thank you, user287001, for your previous input (I learned a few things) as well as for your answer.  It is greatly appreciated.